# Cosmosdb error with gremlin coin filter. Is there an alternative?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, gremlin

Using gremlin g.V().coin(0.5) against CosmosDB throws an error. Is there another way to randomly filter out a traverser?

ExceptionType : GraphCompileException
ExceptionMessage : Gremlin Query Compilation Error: Unable to bind to method 'coin', with arguments of type: (Decimal)
        1 Error(s)
Source : Microsoft.Azure.Graphs
        Context : graphcompute
        Scope : graphparse-translate-csharpexpressionbinding
        GraphStatusCode : ScriptEvaluationError
        HResult : 0x80131500

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your description, I checked the Gremlin steps supported by Azure Cosmos DB and found that the **Coin Step** is not listed. Then, I checked the whole reference on Gremlin about [Coin Step](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#coin-step):

> To randomly filter out a traverser, use the coin()-step (filter). The provided **double argument** biases the "coin toss."
>
> [default GraphTraversal coin(double probability)](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/javadocs/3.3.2/core/org/apache/tinkerpop/gremlin/process/traversal/dsl/graph/GraphTraversal.html#coin-double-)

From the error response you provided mentioned as follows:

> ExceptionType : GraphCompileException ExceptionMessage : Gremlin Query Compilation Error: **Unable to bind to method 'coin', with arguments of type: (Decimal)** 1 Error(s) Source : Microsoft.Azure.Graphs Context : graphcompute Scope : graphparse-translate-csharpexpressionbinding GraphStatusCode : ScriptEvaluationError HResult : 0x80131500

I just tried to execute the following Gremlin query on Azure Portal and found it could work.

> g.V().coin(0.5d)

Comment: Excellent. Adding the "d" solves the problem. Interestingly Amazon Neptune works without the "d". Thanks.